# Architectural Diagrams

Tags: architecture, diagram

I'm trying to build a picture of all the databases, environments, and servers for the project I'm working on. I've never done this before so don't know what software would suffice and be the best.

Suggestions please.....

Comment: Are you looking for open-source/free/commercial... software?

Comment: Ideally free but may consider paying.

Comment: Ok, then StarUml, see my answer, is worth looking at...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even MS oriented consulting companies advise to use Enterprise Architect from Sparx Systems. It is cheap, 200 dolar for a professional license! It is complete, does all the diagrams you can think of and more!

[image]

Comment: +1 - I find the diagramming functionality superior to Visio, and it's great for building up a Model of the solution (not just diagramming).

Answer (score 1):

We have successfully used [MS Visio](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio/) to draw architectural diagrams, environment(dev/QA/Prod) and hardware(IP Addresss/routers/Server) diagrams, and Database Schema diagrams. It's not free but it's usually available in enterprises (with MS Office).

Answer (score 1):

If you want something free, you can try [Dia](http://live.gnome.org/Dia):

[image: Dia]

It runs on Windows, Mac OS X, and Linux. You can get the installer for Windows here (assuming you're using Windows): http://dia-installer.de/

Answer (score 1):

If you want a free tool, have a look at [StarUML](http://staruml.sourceforge.net/en/). It's quite good.

Answer (score 0):

I used MS Visio, its good, using reverse engineering option it can generate the ER diagram from an existing database.